# Convert Height to Centimeter in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert height in centimeter my code works well when i have height for eg: `4'5'' - 134cm` so i am splitting the text using `split("'")`
and it's working fine.

```
public double convertToCMs(String str){
    double c = 0;
    String[] x = str.split("'");
    try{
        c = (Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim()) * 12 + Integer.parseInt(x[1].trim().split("\"")[0])) * 2.54;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c;
}
```

But problem occurs when I have height like `6' - 182cm` because in `x[1] -182` gets passed. Could any one help me out in such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] x=str.trim().split("'");  //newly added.
if (x.length > 2 ) your code;
else c=(Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim())*12)*2.54;
```

Comment: Everytime i am getting length of 2 i tried above code

Comment: then in first split, try trim() first.   String[] x=str.trim().split("'");

Comment: Thanks worked but i did if (x.length >2 ) your code;
else c=(Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim())*12)*2.54;

Comment: Okey, fixed for someone to see in the future~~ :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the array. If height is entered a 6' then only one element will be present in the array. Testing this code and it is working.

```
public double convertToCMs(String str){
double c=0;
String[] x=str.split("'");
try{

if(x.length > 1)
{
    c=(Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim())*12+Integer.parseInt(x[1].trim().split("\"")[0]))*2.54;
}
else
{
    c=(Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim())*12)*2.54;
}

}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SO35575713 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertToCMs("6'"));
    }

    public static double convertToCMs(String str){
        double c = 0;
        String[] x = str.split("'", 2);

        if(x[1].trim().isEmpty()){
            x[1] = "0";
        }

        try{
            c = (Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim()) * 12 + Integer.parseInt(x[1].trim().split("\"")[0])) * 2.54;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static double convertToCMs(String str)
{
    double c = 0;
    double d = 0;
    try
    {
        String[] x = str.split(" - ")[0].split("'");
        c = Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim()) * 12;
        if (x.length > 1)
        {
            c = c + Integer.parseInt(x[1].trim().split("\"")[0]);
        }
        d = c * 2.54;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark it as such by pressing the "up" arrow. Thanks :)